# home_url() links in wordpress site is getting redirected to some other url

Tags: wordpress

I have developed a website in wordpress (wordpress 3.5)
Initially all the links were like : `http://localhost:1053/wp`
Later, to make it accessible from other computers (outside the intranet),
I mapped it with a url something like : `http://somesite.com/wp`

I have changed the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) in the **settings->general** page in admin area.
I have also changed the links in navigation (wherever required).

Now, the issue is that when I click on the logo (link), it redirects me to some other url (`http://somesite.com:1053/wp`). This happens with the action of search form also.

I have used `<?php echo home_url(); ?>` in the href.
When I check it in the page source, the href shows `http://somesite.com/wp`
But it still gets redirected to `http://somesite.com:1053/wp`

Every other relative link is working fine.

I don't understand what is wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

[SOLVED]

I solved the issue by replacing the statement `<?php echo home_url(); ?>` with this `<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>`.

Comment: Maybe there's another setting somewhere you forgot?  Here's a full list of what to change when changing a blog's domain: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by replacing

```
<?php echo home_url(); ?>
```

by

```
<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>
```

It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Run this bad boy: http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

It will run a full find and replace on your database (old url to new url), as well as updating the length of the serialized arrays.  Just make sure you delete it when you're done!

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I had already tried that. But that didn't solved the problem. The problem was in my theme, as in other themes it was working fine. So, I replaced `<?php echo home_url(); ?>` with `<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>` and it works fine now.